# How can I set the height of the tab bar and status bar in dwb?

Tags: dwb

I'm using dwb, which seems to be a brilliant browser, but it has the problem that the tab bar and the status bar are way too small. I've looked at the man page and the website, but I can't find any information on changing the size of either.

I've even tried adding two lines to `~/.config/dwb/settings`:

```
tabbar-height=20
statusbar-height=20
```

But it has no effect.

Is this possible with dwb? If so, how?

Answer (score 0):

The settings `tabbar-height` and `statusbar-height` were added on 2014-03-24, but I was using a version from 2014-03-07.

As of 2014-03-24, these two options work, but do not affect the font size.